# Complete list of merged mineable coins? SHA256 + Scrypt

Tags: altcoin, namecoin, merged-mining

mmpool.org mines these SHA256 PoW coins:

- Bitcoin
- Namecoin
- Ixcoin
- Devcoin
- I0coin
- Groupcoin

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Merged_mining_specification claims that it is only used by Namecoin

Is there a complete list of merge-mineable SHA256 and/or Scrypt based PoW coins available?

Or is anyone willing to compile one?

Comment: fusioncoin & huntercoin can be added to the list

Comment: i made one here: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=769073.0 its a bit out of date but has most of them

Comment: Compiling lists of things or reviewing and recommending services are both off-topic here -- so voting to close this four-years old unanswered question.